# Can't change directories

Tags: python, powershell, directory

I'm very new to coding, and I'm in the beginning of the book "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way".

The book tells me to go to Powershell and type `python ex1.py` so that it will run ex1.py, but if I do that it says

```
C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe:
can't open file 'ex1.py':
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

After some research I got the idea that I need to change directories into lpthw, which is where `ex1.py` is.

So, I'm trying to change directories to open ex1.py, and when I type cd lpthw, it doesn't change directories into lpthw, which is

```
C:\Windows\System32\lpthw
```

but instead it tacks lpthw onto the directory that powershell is in, so it tells me

```
PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> cd lpthw
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\lpthw' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd lpthw
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...hell\v1.0\lpthw:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE   xception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

I found one answer online that said to type python and a space, and drag ex1.py into Powershell, but that gives me this again

```
PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> python C:\Windows\System32\lpthw\ex1.py\
C:\Users\Olga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe:
can't open file 'C:\Windows\System32\lpthw\ex1.py\':
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

Soooo ... how do I get it to run ex1.py?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: you are NOT supposed to do ANYTHING in the system directories. **_not NOT N-O-T_** [*grin*] change to your _user directory_. this should work >>> `Set-Location -LiteralPath "$env:HOMEDRIVE$env:HOMEPATH"` <<<

Comment: I did that, and it still won't run ex1.py.  It still says that it doesn't exist.  I also tried doing what you told me and then saying "cd lpthw" and it now it tacks lpthw onto PS C:\Users\Olga, like PS C:\Users\Olga\lpthw, and says it doesn't exist

Comment: i recommend you open file explorer & use that to find the location you need. you have apparently scattered your files and folders nearly at random ... find them and move them to where you can use them - in your user directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is frustrating, but you'll get used to it!

> when I type cd lpthw, it doesn't change directories into lpthw, but instead it tacks lpthw onto the directory that powershell is in

These directory names are an address to describe where something is in the computer. At each `\` the things on the right inside the things on the left. If you have a path starting with `C:` on the left, going through a lot of directories, and ending with the place or file you want to use on the far right, that's a *full path* and you can use it from anywhere, because it describes a complete location with no room for confusion.

Instead, if you use just a short piece of a path like "lpthw" it's known as a *relative path* and it describes how to get somewhere, starting from the current directory.

Relative paths are shorter and more convenient, but potentially confusing because where they end up changes as you move around. Full paths are more effort, but more precise.

This was very close:

```
python C:\Windows\System32\lpthw\ex1.py\
```

The `\` on the right hand side is saying `ex1.py` is a directory, and I think that's your problem. Remove that, so it says:

```
python C:\Windows\System32\lpthw\ex1.py
```

and I think it might work.

That should work, but As Lee_Dailey comments, that *is* a strange place to put it; anything inside `C:\Windows\System32` is best left alone for Windows to manage. At some point, try and find a way to move the whole `C:\Windows\System32\lpthw\` folder into your Documents instead, e.g. `C:\Users\Olga\Documents\lpthw\`

Comment: Thank you!  After I moved lpthw to C:\Users\Olga, it let me change into that directory and then run ex1.py